# Dart Future.doWhile blocks all execution

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I’m struggling a bit to understand why the following code doesn’t work (note: this is a contrived example, I am trying to understand how to use doWhile).

```
bool busy = true;

void doSomething() async {
  await Future.doWhile(() => busy);
  print("done");
}

void doSomethingElse() async {
  await Future.delayed(
    Duration(seconds: 2), (){
      busy = false;
    });
}

void main() {
  print("a");
  doSomething();
  doSomethingElse();
  print("b");
}
```

I would have thought that this would print:

```
a
b
done
```

But it instead just blocks permanently (or at least on dartpad it does). Could someone please help me understand what is wrong here?

My best guess is that the doWhile is repeatedly scheduling itself as soon as it is called so that no other code can ever be executed. If that is the case, how can one use doWhile normally?

(I am aware of Completer and similar, I’m just specifically interested in doWhile here)

Comment: Try to read the implementation: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-async/Future/doWhile.html , it the return value is not a future, it is just a while(cond) loop which blocks the main isolate

Comment: Thank you, after reading that the behaviour I am seeing does make sense. I am still a bit confused as to why this exists though, it seems like it shouldn’t allow one to pass a synchronous function...

Comment: It allows you to pass a function returning `FutureOr<bool>`, which means that you can sometimes return a future, and sometimes a bool directly. That's probably not particularly useful. but it's there, and consistent with other methods taking a potentially asynchronous function.

Comment: @jeremy Do you know how to await in this scenario without stopping the application?